# _.debounce function strange behavour on several inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, lodash, debouncing

I have 4 inputs on a page and such code

```
$('input').on('keyup', _.debounce(function(){
  console.log('Keyup fired')
}, 10000))
```

So in $('input') I have a collection of 4 inputs.
When I start fast-typing in all 4 inputs, 10 seconds after I get only one 'Keyup fired' in the console.

It seems that every input shares the same function.
But on my opinion every input should have it's own instance of _debounce function.

Why am I wrong? According to my opinion, why I write COLLECTION.on(event, fn).
Jquery should map 4 inputs and assign to each one the result of call _.debounce(). So each input will have it own instance of debounced function.
thank you

Answer (score 4):

> It seems that every input shares the same function.

Of course, because you provided single event handler for all of your inputs.

If you want separate handlers then you will need to bind event for each input individually:

```
$('input').each(function() {
  $(this).on('keyup', _.debounce(function() {
    console.log('Keyup fired')
  }, 10000))
})
```

Comment: thank you.. just it seemed strange to me that the same function assigned for every element of the collection... I thought - new _debounce should be assign every time

Comment: new `_.debounce` will of course be unique, but in your case you called `_.debounce` only once, so it uses the same function.

Comment: Dfsq, I tought it should work like in the case of .map(() => ), the function is envoked for every element of the array. But here .on is apparently implemented differently-  here it is invoked only once...

Comment: It invoked only once, because you invoke `.on` only once. `_.debounce` returns new function which will be used as event handler. So you have `$('input').on('keyup', handler)`. Here handler will be shared by all inputs. This is your situation.